# execute ruby as pipeline input for logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

Logstash allows [executing arbitrary commands](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html) as inputs for a pipeline.
Here is my example pipeline:

```
input {
  exec {
    command => '/usr/bin/ruby -e "puts RUBY_VERSION"'
    interval => 10
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

With this I get the following error:

```
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:328:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'logstash-core (= 2.4.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:307:in `each'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:307:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:199:in `start'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182:in `resolve'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `resolve'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
        from /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I also tried running logstash's very own JRuby inside the exec like this

```
input {
  exec {
    command => '/opt/logstash/vendor/jruby/bin/jruby -e "puts RUBY_VERSION"'
    interval => 10
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

and it creates another Bundler error:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'ci_reporter_rspec (= 1.0.0) java' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
  verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found! at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:328
                                    each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
  verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found! at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:307
                                   start at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:199
                                 resolve at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182
                                 resolve at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192
                                   specs at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132
                               specs_for at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177
                         requested_specs at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166
                         requested_specs at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18
                                   setup at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13
                                   setup at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:122
                                  (root) at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18
                                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                                  (root) at /opt/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
```

Logstash keeps running and the pipeline executes every 10 seconds but the message is always empty. Trying to execute other commands like `echo "hello"` works without problems.

Running on logstash 2.4.0, openjdk version "1.8.0_102", system ruby is MRI 2.3.1 on Archlinux ARM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, logstash is installed correctly, it works when i don't try to run ruby commands

Comment: Do you have a `bundle` executable in the directory `/opt/logstash/vendor/jruby/bin`?
I would rather use own jruby installation instead of the packaged by logstash if you are going to use some ruby libraries.

Comment: Do you need to use the exec input, or can you use the tcp input and run your ruby script as a separate process?

Comment: @dieter yes. again: logstash is working perfectly with all my other pipelines. I think I will just file a bug for logstash.

Comment: @jesusaurus this might work but my actual script is reading from serial. and for that i need to have another process exposing something TCPy I have to take care of. Whats the point of the whole thing then? Then I also can skip logstash and send it directly to my remote elasticsearch with my script.

Comment: Logstash would be the "something exposing tcp" since the tcp input opens and listens to a port. And yes, you could then bypass logstash entirely if you want to also implement data parsing and formatting, and then write directly to elasticsearch. Or your script can read from serial and write to logstash over tcp and let logstash do the heavy lifting of parsing and formatting the data with grok filters.

Comment: @Jesusaurus sure but who is taking care that my script runs once in a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might need to switch to JRuby instead of MRI, which is experimental for Logstash and not [currently supported](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3233). You might consider [RVM](https://rvm.io/interpreters/jruby) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which can help manage different Ruby versions and switch between JRuby and native as needed in the shell.

Once you are using JRuby + bundler (`gem install bundler`), you can `bundle install` from the project root and your dependency issues should be resolved.

Comment: I tried that and it ddidnt work out. I installed the dependencies of my script within logstash's jruby env and run my script with the very same jruby and it still didnt work. See the updated question with a jruby example

Comment: Again, its not about logstash or my command, because I don't use any libraries (see example in the question). Also logstash is working fine for all other pipelines.

Comment: Looks like good progress. You can see this logstash issue for the same error message. Does the Gemfile.lock have gems listed in it? edited: deleted rebuild instructions

Comment: By using the embedded jruby, `bundler` is being invoked with all Gemfile dependencies by default. Logstash does not ship with `ci_reporter_rspec` as it is in the `:development` group, thus the error. You can see it in the [source code here](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/1-9-stable/lib/bundler.rb#L114), which reflects this line from your error log: `/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18`. I think you best best is to invoke Ruby commands with `jruby`